# How to install Java on Arch Linux

Tags: java, archlinux, manjaro

According to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Java I can install Open JDK 7 on a clean Arch Linux installation by invoking the command

```
pacman -S jdk7-openjdk
```

But when doing so, I get an error saying

```
error: target not found: jdk7-openjdk
```

I already commented out my nearest Pacman repository in `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist` and ran a first update by invoking pacman -Syu hoping that this would cause the package above to be discovered.

**How can I install Open JDK 7 on Arch Linux using pacman?**

Edit: I'm running a Raspberry Pi with an ARM processor and I'm hoping to get a Java build that is tailored for its hardware and uses the OS hardware floating point support.

Comment: Does `pacman -Ss openjdk` find the package you're looking for?

Comment: It finds one, `extra/openjdk6 6.b24_1.11.4-1`. I tried several combinations, but pacman -S openjdk6 was not one of them. It's an old version, and it seems to give me just a JRE instead of a complete JDK.

Comment: which java do you need, for running software or for development? jre or jdk?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Get the best mirror near you (check [this list](https://www.archlinux.org/mirrors/)); you can even generate a new mirror list on the [archlinux website](https://www.archlinux.org/mirrorlist/).
Then run `# pacman -Syy; # pacman -Su; # pacman -S jdk8-openjdk` (or `jre8-openjdk` if you only need the JRE)

Comment: +1, this is (almost) the way I would do it. One note, do **NOT** do `pacman -Syy`, use `pacman -Syu`. Partial upgrades are unsupported.

Comment: Correct. You should always perform an update after a -Sy (or -Syy).

Comment: You can compress all of this into `# pacman -Syyu jdk8-opoenjdk`

Answer (score 4):

Try the following command:

```
pacman -S jre7-openjdk
```

Answer (score 3):

OpenJDK is a dependency on multiple Arch Linux packages so just installing Oracle’s JDK wasn’t enough.

First had to remove icedtea-web

```
sudo pacman -R icedtea-web
```

Then build Oracle JRE AUR package,

Before installing OracleJRE I had to remove openjdk6 manually and ignore dependencies:

```
[argy@Freak jre]$ sudo pacman -Rdd openjdk6
```

Install OracleJRE

```
sudo pacman -U jre-7u2-1-i686.pkg.tar.xz
```

Build and Install JDK AUR package:

```
sudo pacman -U jdk-7u2-1-i686.pkg.tar.xz
```

Logout and Login so the PATH gets updated and java is installed.

Comment: Please do not advise users to install unofficial packages right away while the piece of software OP is looking for is available in an official repo. OP should maybe just refresh the package lists first `pacman -Sy`. Answer from ilpianista is the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

Just a quick observation:

When you change your repository it is a good idea to update using `pacman -Syyu` as this will refresh all the packages.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
pacman -S java7-openjdk
```

Comment: That looked encouraging, but too bad: `Target not found` :-(

Comment: That should actually be pacman -S jdk7-openjdk. Now you can replace the 7 with 8 or 9.

Answer (score 1):

RB based on armv6l. checking [here](http://archlinuxarm.org/packages) you can see that there is not packaged version of openjdk for armv6l.

and here is what my arch on raspi shows

```
   [root@raspi ~]# pacman -Ss openjdk
    extra/openjdk6 6.b24_1.11.4-1
    Free Java environment based on OpenJDK 6.0 with IcedTea6 replacing binary plugs.
   [root@raspi ~]#
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you may completely skip `pacman` and take full control:

- Download the `tar.gz` of the JDK version you need from https://adoptopenjdk.net/
- Expand the archive: `tar zxvf OpenJDKxxx.ta.gz`
- Move the JDK to `/opt`: `sudo mv jdk-xxx /opt`
- Update the `PATH`:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/jdk-xxx
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

- Test: `java -version`

This way you can install as many different versions of the JDK you want and switch between them by changing the value of `PATH`

Answer (score 0):

Due to the current procedure of downloading and installing of Oracle JDK, you may not able to do that easily with linux environment. Because lots of previously supported JDK packages are not working now. if you wish to install **Oracle JDK-8** on your **arch-linux / manjaro** machine, [this gist](https://gist.github.com/RavinduSachintha/1b41eeed5e1fcb84ec71f2e26854274e) will guide you well.

The solution will be briefly as below.

1. First need to clone relevant JDK git to your PC.

   `cd ~/Downloads && git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/jdk8.git`
2. Now you should have a jdk8 folder in Downloads. Move that ".tar.gz" which you downloaded from oracle to that folder, If it is also in downloads, and I got the filename right, the command would be like this.

   `mv ~/Downloads/jdk-8u212-linux-x64.tar.gz ~/Downloads/jdk8/`
3. Now we will enter the jdk8 folder and should edit the PKGBUILD.

   `cd jdk8 && nano PKGBUILD`
4. The source line we want to change from is....
   `"https://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/${pkgver}-${_build}/${_hash}/${_pkgname}-${pkgver}-linux-x64.tar.gz"` to the filename we now have in folder, `jdk-8u212-linux-x64.tar.gz`
5. Save and exit the PKGBUILD. Now we can build and install from within that directory.

   `makepkg -sric`
6. If everything looks like it went fine you can just remove that directory when you are done.

   `cd ~ && rm -r ~/Downloads/jdk8`

Comment: Please add some explanation too, as links may die one day

Comment: Thanks for the guidance and updated an improved answer.